# How to restrict a user to login our application if anybody already logged in the same browser?

Tags: php, cookies

I have one PHP Application.Now i want to restrict a user to login my application if anybody already logged in the same browser? Is this possible using Cookie? which is better way of doing this?

How i do it...

Comment: someone using the same browser would surely be the same person? if so they will already have the session established and have access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cookies to store the session id. Then the browser can be associated to only one session at a time. Use the session to store whether the user logged in. On the login page ask the session whether the user already logged in.

As with all network communication, this requires a certain amount of trust in the transmitting end (i. e. the Browser). It should therefore not be used for high risk scenarios. It's, however, the best you can get.

Answer (score 2):

If you use PHP sessions, the default is to use cookies to store session information, so if someone opens a new window it will be already logged in and have the session.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the session management (which, I believe, that you would be using) should handle this. 
If a person A logs in and then Person B tries to open the login page in the same browser to log in, the application should redirect the login page to the application main page eg. Dashboard page.